# For loop and by function error with R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I everybody !

I'm discovering the R world for my PhD work and I have several problems when I want to implement loop to simplify analysis.

My data frame is :

```
'data.frame':   3581 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Date          : Factor w/ 7 levels "03-03-17","10-02-17",..: 
 $ Experimentator: Factor w/ 9 levels "BURLET","DECHAUD",..: 
 $ Origin        : Factor w/ 3 levels "FRANCE","JAPAN",..: 
 $ City          : Factor w/ 6 levels "MONTPELLIER",..: 
 $ Lineage       : Factor w/ 27 levels "L21","L22","L26",..:
 $ Sex           : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male":
 $ ccr           : int  1183 1813 1866 1745 1210 1463 2477 1506
```

The first 6 are my factors and the last my quantitative variable.
I need to work with several factors in same time, then when I want to do a shapiro.test for example :
with by:

```
by(data$ccr, c(data$Date, data$Sex, data$Lineage), shapiro.test() )
Error in tapply(seq_len(3581L), list(`c(data$Date, data$Sex, 
data$Lineage)` = c(2L,  : the arguments must have the same length
```

With a for loop it's hard to me so I tried to write :

```
for(sex in levels(data$Sex)){
  for(date in levels(data$Date)){
    for(lineage in levels(data$Lineage)){
      shapiro.test(data$ccr[,lineage])
    }
  }
}
```

bu I don't know how to increment my loop...

Thank for any help !

Comment: You should at least tell us which package(s) you are using here.

Comment: you need for all 3581 records?

Comment: In `by`, the grouping variables (`INDICES`) should be "a _`list`_ of factors". Compare `by(mtcars, c(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am), function(dat) shapiro.test(dat$mpg))` (your case), with `by(mtcars, list(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am), function(dat) shapiro.test(dat$mpg))`.

Comment: Great !!

Thank for the by() function, it was simple ! and efficient, now i just need to learn how save result in a file but it's great !

The for loop doesn't work :

Error in ccr_global $ ccr [, lineage]: incorrect number of dimensions
The by solution seem to be the best choice !

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops are not necessary to do this in R. I don't think using the `by()` function is the best way either. The easiest way would be to use the [dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) infrastructure :

`library(dplyr)`

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Sex, Date, Lineage) %>% 
  filter(n() > 2)  %>%
  summarise(shapiro_pvalue = shapiro.test(ccr)$p.value,
            shapiro_stat = shapiro.test(ccr)$statistic)
```

`filter(n() > 2)` handles the fact that `shapiro.test` needs at least 3 samples to be computed. 
(Credits to [Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46753613/5678813) for the good reproducible example !)

[dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) is  quite different from `base R`, but if you are starting your PhD and need to use R, it is worth using it if you want to make your life simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index to run like this

```
index <- 1

while(index != 3582){
  for(sex in levels(data$Sex)){
    for(date in levels(data$Date)){
      for(lineage in levels(data$Lineage)){
        shapiro.test(data$ccr[,lineage])
        index <- index + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using base R but instead of `by` use `split/lapply`.
First, some fake data, with it's name changed to `dat` since `data` already is an R function.

```
set.seed(9235)    # make it reproducible
n <- 3581
d <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "day")
d <- format(d, "%d-%m-%y")
dat <- data.frame(
    Date = sample(d, n, TRUE),
    Experimentator = sample(LETTERS[1:9], n, TRUE),
    Origin = sample(LETTERS[11:13], n, TRUE),
    Lineage = sample(paste0("L", 1:27), n, TRUE),
    Sex = sample(c("F", "M"), n, TRUE),
    ccr = sample(3000, n, TRUE)
)
```

Now the code. Note that `shapiro.test` only accepts data with `number of non-missing values must be between 3 and 5000.`

```
sp <- split(dat$ccr, list(dat$Date, dat$Sex, dat$Lineage))
sp <- sp[which(sapply(sp, function(x) length(x) > 2))]

result <- lapply(sp, shapiro.test)
```